# Detecting if two given strings are isomorphic using Java data structures

Tags: java, algorithm, strings, interview-questions, hash-map

So I have written the following code and it works for various same length isomorphic strings I have tried. However I am not sure what are some time complexity improvements and coding tweaks that could be applied to the code:

```
/**
 * Created by mona on 5/26/16.
 */
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Collections;

public class IsomorphicStrings {
    //the words "abca" and "zbxz" are isomorphic
    //aabc a(2) b(1) c(1)
    //zzbx z(2) b(1) x(1)
    //my algorithm
    //create a sorted hashmap  on value
    //check to see if two hashmap are equal based on their value set
    //assuming two isomorphic strings are of the same length

    public static boolean areIsomorphic(String s1, String s2) {
        Map<Character, Integer> freqMap1 = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Character, Integer> freqMap2 = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i=0; i<s1.length(); i++) {
            if (freqMap1.containsKey(s1.charAt(i))) {
                int freq1 = freqMap1.get(s1.charAt(i));
                freqMap1.put(s1.charAt(i), freq1 + 1);
            } else {
                freqMap1.put(s1.charAt(i), 1);
            }

        }

        for (int i=0; i<s2.length(); i++) {
            if (freqMap2.containsKey(s2.charAt(i))) {
                int freq2 = freqMap2.get(s2.charAt(i));
                freqMap2.put(s2.charAt(i), freq2 + 1);
            }
            else {
                freqMap2.put(s2.charAt(i), 1);
            }

        }

        List<Integer> freqList1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> freqList2 = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Map.Entry entry: freqMap1.entrySet()) {
            freqList1.add((Integer) entry.getValue());
        }

        for (Map.Entry entry: freqMap2.entrySet()) {
            freqList2.add((Integer) entry.getValue());
        }

        Collections.sort(freqList1);
        Collections.sort(freqList2);

        return freqList1.equals(freqList2);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1="abca";
        String s2="zbxz";
        System.out.println(areIsomorphic(s1, s2));
    }
}
```

/* side note: can isomorphic strings be of different lengths? Then what algorithm do you suggest? */

Comment: can you explain why there was two vote downs on this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that your coding style is improving. What comes to the concept of isomorphism, two strings of different length should never be considered isomorphic due to the definition of isomorphism:

Two strings \$S_1 = c_1 c_2 \dots c_n\$ and \$S_2 = c'_1 c'_2 \dots c'_n\$ are isomorphic if and only if there exists a bijection \$f\$ such that \$c'_i = f(c_i)\$ for all \$i = 1, 2, \dots, n\$.

What comes to your algorithm, you could rewrite it a little bit more succintly:

```
public static boolean areIsomorphic(String s1, String s2) {
    if (s1.length() != s2.length()) {
        return false;
    }

    Map<Character, Integer> frequencyMap1 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Character, Integer> frequencyMap2 = new HashMap<>();

    for (char c : s1.toCharArray()) {
        frequencyMap1.put(c, frequencyMap1.getOrDefault(c, 0) + 1);
    }

    for (char c : s2.toCharArray()) {
        frequencyMap2.put(c, frequencyMap2.getOrDefault(c, 0) + 1);
    }

    List<Integer> freqList1 = new ArrayList<>(frequencyMap1.values());       
    List<Integer> freqList2 = new ArrayList<>(frequencyMap2.values());

    Collections.sort(freqList1);
    Collections.sort(freqList2);

    return freqList1.equals(freqList2);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You have simplified the implementation but preserved the error in the algorithm: this function tests whether the inputs are isomorphic anagrams of each other.

Answer (score 4):

Your build two `HashMap<Character, Integer>`, then two `ArrayList<Integer>`, then sort the lists, then compare the lists.  Your logic is too complicated, I think.  Furthermore, you aren't taking advantage of the symmetry in the problem — nearly every line of code appears in duplicate. Even worse, the code doesn't even do what you claim; rather, it tests whether the inputs are isomorphic anagrams of each other.

Going by the definition, we can just build a character-to-character map from one string to the other, and fail as soon as we encounter an unexpected character.  This should be O(*n*), and possibly faster if a mismatch is detected early.

The code works equally well on any pair of `CharSequence`s, not just `String`s, so we might as well generalize.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class IsomorphicStrings {
    public static boolean areIsomorphic(CharSequence s1, CharSequence s2) {
        return isSurjective(s1, s2) && isSurjective(s2, s1);
    }

    private static boolean isSurjective(CharSequence s1, CharSequence s2) {
        if (s1.length() != s2.length()) return false;

        Map<Character, Character> surjection = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
            char c1 = s1.charAt(i);
            char c2 = s2.charAt(i);
            Character prev = surjection.put(c1, c2);
            if (prev != null && prev != c2) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(areIsomorphic(args[0], args[1]));
    }
}
```

Comment: [Related answer in Ruby](/a/88499/9357)

Answer (score 0):

/* Sorry for the above post but in corner test cases my algorithm failed. Here's the complete non-failing algorithm */

```
/**
 * Created by mona on 5/26/16.
 */

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class IsomorphicStrings {
    //the words "abca" and "zbxz" are isomorphic

    public static boolean areIsomorphic(String s1, String s2) {
        Map<Character, ArrayList<Integer>> charPos1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        Map<Character, ArrayList<Integer>> charPos2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        for (int i=0; i<s1.length(); i++) {
            if (charPos1.containsKey(s1.charAt(i))) {
                charPos1.get(s1.charAt(i)).add(i);
            } else {
                charPos1.put(s1.charAt(i), new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(i)));
            }

        }

        for (int i=0; i<s2.length(); i++) {
            if (charPos2.containsKey(s2.charAt(i))) {
                charPos2.get(s2.charAt(i)).add(i);
            } else {
                charPos2.put(s2.charAt(i), new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(i)));
            }
        }
        return new ArrayList<>(charPos1.values()).equals(new ArrayList<>(charPos2.values()));
        //return freqMap1.values().equals(freqMap2.values()); won't work
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1="foo";
        String s2="app";
        System.out.println(areIsomorphic(s1, s2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you write me the two strings that made your algorithm fail?

Comment: The one I have written as answer is correct. The one in the question fails with "abb" and "bab" that is why I am using `LinkedHashMap`

Comment: That's odd: I copy pasted your original algorithm and it returns **`true`** for *abb* and *bab*.

Comment: try to copypaste it accordingly to https://leetcode.com/problems/isomorphic-strings/ and it will fail on one of the cases.

Comment: regardless `leetcode` doesn't accept use of `LinkedHashMap` which is so weird honestly!!

Comment: Did you try importing explicitly **LinkedHashMap**?

Comment: @MonaJalal on leetcode you can use everything from the JDK, but some classes are not imported by default, so you need to add `import java.util.LinkedHashMap;` explicitly

Comment: @coderodde you need the `LinkedHashMap` to guarantee sorting order. `HashMap` doesn't guarantee that, but with short strings like "abb" and "bab" you might get the right ordering simply by chance. The ordering of elements in a `HashMap` may vary with JVM implementation and version

Comment: @janos No I don't. All we need here is the frequency maps for both the strings, after which we ask via **`values()`** the actual frequencies, sort them, and if it turns out that the sorted frequency lists are same by content, we know that the input strings are isomorphic. Also, **`LinkedHashMap`** does not sort the mappings by their keys, but rather by their insertion order.

Comment: Janos is right! You might by chance get the right order. Order is not guaranteed in HashMap.